# Sup, Inf, Min, Max

Tags: functional-analysis

For the two inequalities

1. $x$ is an element of the rationals where $x^2 < 3$
2. $x$ is an element of the rationals where $x^2 > 3$

I am having trouble with the concepts would these be correct?

1. $\sup$: $\sqrt3$, $\inf$: $-\sqrt{3}$, $\max$: DNE, $\min$: DNE
2. $\sup$: $\sqrt3$, $\inf$: $-\sqrt{3}$, $\max$: DNE, $\min$: DNE

Comment: You're almost right. Let $A = \{ x \in \mathbb Q : x^2 < 3 \}$ and $B = \{ x \in \mathbb Q : x^2 > 3 \}$. Then $\sup A = \sqrt 3$, $\inf A = -\sqrt 3$, and neither a max nor a min exists. But $\sup B = \infty$ since there are arbitrarily large rationals whose square is greater than 3, and $\inf B = -\infty$, as there are arbitrarily small (large magnitude negative) rationals whose square is greater than 3. Similarly, the maxima and minima do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, note that $9^2>3$.

I have just prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is not the supremum.

In fact, for any rational number, $q$ that is bigger than $\sqrt{3}$, $q^2>3$, hence the supremum is $\infty$

The infimum is not correct too, are you able to fix it?